# Create example string from the given regex

Tags: python, regex

My python function accepts any regex in a string and it has to create a sample string from the given regex. Is there any way to do that? For ex - if supplied regex is `r'^\d{5}$'`, it should return '12345'. Please suggest.

Comment: just supply an example with your regular expression. this is way to complicated otherwise.

Comment: @phoet I have developed a validation module where I validate parameters for their formats(regexes). I validate these parameters against regexes like r'^\d{5}$',r'^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$',r'^\D{2}$', etc. Suppose I get some string which has to be validated against r'^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$' and if it fails that validation, I have to tell user that sample format as 123-45-6789.

Comment: the regular expression language is quite complex. i don't know if you can reverse engineer the code paths behind that. you could get away with parsing the thing with regex though :D

Comment: maybe python has some module that allows you to have a look into the abstract syntax tree of a regular expression, but i assume that it is none trivial to derive an example from that.

Answer (score 0):

I know `ZERO` about python so i'll wing it for the fun of it, as it's time it learnt some:

```
import re
r = '^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$'
k = 0
ret = ''
cnt = re.findall('\d', r)

for i in cnt:          # loop the number of times a digit was found
    for j in range(i): # loop the number of digits in regex
      ret += (k += 1)  # add digits to return var
    ret += '-'         # add hypen '-'
ret = ret[:-1]         # remove last hypen
```

I hope I got indentation right! but this is my first try at python so if this doesn't work oh well, but you should get the idea:

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It will work for the given regex. However if I change regex, logic has to be changed accordingly. Can I somehow make it generic?